# How to save map cache of my city on SD card for use with Google Maps, possibly with no expiry?

Tags: sd-card, google-maps, cache

I don't have enough rep. to comment under other's post, so I had to open this thread. I read some threads on Google Maps here and the question still persists.

Is there a straightforward method to cache my city's map strictly onto the SD card (as I am running out of internal space), possibly in a way that this cache doesn't get deleted in 30 days? On the other hand it would be cool if it auto-updated itself with the latest map updates, points of interests from Google, strictly when on Wi-Fi.

I already heard of Google's native solution, and of [Brut Mod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630887) -- but don't know if any of the two would come close to my goal. How can I achieve it?

Edit. Added link for Brut Mod. Sorry, don't have the link any more for that other question.

Comment: *Hmpf* That would belong to the category *Recommendations* again, and thus be off topic according to our [FAQ]. A little re-phrasing could save it from that fate, let me see... How about this? A link to that "Brut Mod" would be helpful (never heard of it). And a link to that "other post" as reference.

Comment: Isn't it like I'm looking for a solution to a problem?

Comment: I didn't flag it for closure, as a re-phrasing converted it from "which one is better" (speculative/subjective/recommendation) to "how can I solve my problem" and thus made it on-topic again (I tried to be helpful, and preventing your question from being closed ;) [How To Ask Android Questions The Smart Way](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-ask-android-questions-the-smart-way) provides some more very useful hints btw ;) // Thanks for the added links, I will dive into it.

Comment: Looks like your question just was reduced by the "Brut Mod". On the last page of that XDA thread you'll find: *These Maps apk files have been removed due to a copyright infringement complaint from Google.* Which only leaves you with either Google Labs own pre-caching -- or taking a look at e.g. [Maps (+)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coderminus.maps).

Comment: So did this solve your issue? Shall I convert it into an answer?